# Spring Data JPA Primary Key Violation Constraint Not Working

Tags: spring-data-jpa, primary-key, h2

### Code and Configuration :

DB used - H2 in Memory database

### **User Entity :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 455202739064202185L;
    
    @Id // please note is not auto generated but manually generated 
    @Column(name = "id",unique=true)
    @NotNull
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    @NotEmpty(message = "First name is required")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Last name is required")
    private String lastName;    
    
    @Column(name = "email")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Email is required")
    @Email(message="Email Must be well formed")
    private String email;
    
    
}
```

### **UserRepository :**

```
public interface UserJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    
}
```

### **UserServiceImpl :**

```
this.userJpaRepository.saveAll(users);
```

### **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.exostar</groupId>
    <artifactId>FileUpload</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FileUpload</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
           <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

### Issue :

As per the User entity class , `@Id` is manually generated.
(I have a CSV file which has Id field which is read in User entity)
So Id is not auto generated

Whenever I call `this.userJpaRepository.saveAll(users)` and even when there is an `User entity` with Id already existing , the `User entity` gets overwritten.
That is , `Id` with same entity gets overwritten with new data.

It has to throw - U`nique index or primary key violation error`

However, when I try to insert **duplicate entry into H2 database MANUALLY** , it throws exception - `Unique index or primary key violation`

I also tried adding `unique=true` to Id field in User Entity but its not working
Can anybody please help on resolving this issue please ?

Comment: That is because `save()` updates when id is present. You have to manually check for the presence of id

Answer (score 0):

Well as it turns out that the behavior that you are seeing is because of the call to `em.merge(...)`  in the `save()` implementation. Here is what actually happens:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null.");

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity); // Update if the entity is not new
    }
}
```

This is a sample code from `SimpleJpaRepository` implementation. you can use your own query methods for updating the existing query something like this:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.firstname = ?1 where u.lastname = ?2")
int setFixedFirstnameFor(String firstname, String lastname);
```